# Decrease of number results between 2 operations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm facing a strange SQL problem, I have there 2 requests:

```
INSERT INTO tmp_copy 
SELECT champs 
FROM tmp 
WHERE champs IN (SELECT champs FROM myTable)

COPY (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE champs IN (SELECT champs FROM tmp_copy)) 
TO 'bla/bla.csv' WITH DELIMITER ';';
```

This operation is as simple as it looks like.

The first request put in the table "tmp_copy" the common lines between tmp and myTable, and the second request put in a file the inverse operation.

But in the process, I lost a lot of results and I don't know why. For me the number result should be the same...

Comment: Can you show the process step by step with counts?  Run SELECT count(1) from tmp_copy; SELECT count(1) FROM tmp WHERE champs IN (SELECT champs FROM myTable); Then run the insert statement.  Then run SELECT count(1) FROM myTable WHERE champs IN (SELECT champs FROM tmp_copy).

Comment: Why would it be the same? There's nothing indicating that champs is unique.in tmp and myTable.